# Finding nodes within an XML element that has attributes?

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, attributes, element

Currently I'm trying to parse xml. When I use  as the container, all of the information is returned correctly. When I use  the program doesn't return any information

So when I try to list nodes using THIS XML format, everything works correctly;

```
<feed>
<entry>
<childnode1>blue</childnode1>
<childnode2>red</childnode2>
<childnode3>green</childnode3>
<childnode4>yellow</childnode4>
</entry>
</feed>
```

But I need it to work in this format; (This DOESN'T currently work)

```
<feed xmlns='x' xmlns:openSearch='y' xmlns:gsx='z'>
<entry>
<childnode1>blue</childnode1>
<childnode2>red</childnode2>
<childnode3>green</childnode3>
<childnode4>yellow</childnode4>
</entry>
</feed>
```

So in the first example XML I gave, this program works perfectly;

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml

Module ParsingUsingXmlDocument

Sub Main()

    Dim document As XmlDocument
    Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim node As XmlNode

    document = New XmlDocument()
    document.Load("C:\Users\Joe\Documents\family.xml")
    nodelist = document.SelectNodes("/feed/entry")

    For Each node In nodelist
        Dim stockinfo = node.ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText
        Console.WriteLine("Info: " & stockinfo)
        Console.Write(vbCrLf)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub


End Module
```

But when I use the second xml format I showed, where  has attributes, nothing works. My program is just completely blank.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just [**deserialize**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-Part-III-XML-Serialization) the XML?

Answer (score 2):

try using the [GetElementsByTagName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

Change:

```
nodelist = document.SelectNodes("/feed/entry")
```

to:

```
nodelist = document.GetElementsByTagName("entry")
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns='x' xmlns:openSearch='y' xmlns:gsx='z'` - These are not attributes, these are namespace declarations.

Your xml document has namespaces, so you must take them into account.

```
Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
document.Load("C:\Users\Joe\Documents\family.xml")

Dim uri As String = "x"
Dim manager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable)
manager.AddNamespace("ns", uri)

Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes("/ns:feed/ns:entry", manager)

For Each node As XmlNode In nodelist
    Dim stockinfo = node.ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText
    Console.WriteLine("Info: " & stockinfo)
    Console.Write(vbCrLf)
Next
```

Instead of explicitly specifying the namespace, you can get it from the node:

```
Dim uri As String = document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy with xml linq.  The namespace is giving you the issue

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement entry = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "entry").FirstOrDefault();

            string[] resutls = entry.Elements().Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```